# Why does my domain show an SSL from another domain?

Tags: lets-encrypt

I've deleted the Letsencrypt SSL for my domain, now i cannot access it through http. I am prompted to bypass the warning by my browser (Chrome and Firefox), and access it throught the strike through https (the site is www.phpninja.fr.
However this domain resolves to another virtualhost in my dedicated server (www.creatissus.com), which i find strange, since the config file for this domain has no redirect to the other domain. IT seems to be a misconfiguration of one of the apache config file, (I can provide if needed). I wonder if you can spot the problem without me providing it. Thanks

Comment: You redirected to HTTPS, so you have to have some sort of TLS certificate. Get a new one.

Comment: The problem is i cannot get a certificate with certbot-auto using the webroot method, since the web root is not accessible

Comment: So change the document root, or the permissions, or something else, and make it work.

Comment: I ended backing my DB and php files, and recreate the vhost in Webmin

Answer (score 0):

The apache config also depends on the web hosting site, which does its own mapping depending on how the service is set. Maybe it sets to your primary domain SSL certificate by default if no SSL certificate is set for your other doamin, assuming you are using the same web hosting service.

Comment: Can you tell me more about how it sets the primary domain?